# Algorithm design. Optimal, most efficient solution

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have a small problem that I want to solve. I would love to come up with optimal solution and I was thinking recursion would probably be the best choice here. Let me know if you think my solution is ideal, or if you can think there is a better way.

Here's the problem:
I have a list of cities. The algorithm I want is to determine how many degrees a city is from Washington DC. Each city has a list of highways that go through it. If a city shares any highway with Washington DC then it's 1 degree from it. If a city doesn't share a highway with Washington DC, but shares a highway with a city that's 1 degree from Washington DC, then that city is 2 degrees away, and son.

I was thinking of creating a list of highways and each highway should have a list of all the cities it goes through. Then I loop through all the highways that go through Washington DC and for each highway I look at all the cities it goes through and then recursively check each of these cities to see eventually a highway will make it to Washington DC and this way I can get the number of degrees.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: How about BFS? So from the origin city you explore each neighbour, add the degree by one. When you reach Washington DC, return the value of the degree.

Comment: What if there are multiple degrees ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to construct a graph where the nodes are cities and there is an undirected edge between cities A and B if and only if there is a highway connecting A and B. Then the degree is the length of a shortest path (all edges have length 1) between the respective cities. You can find this with breadth first search.

How to enumerate the edges?  For each highway just use two nested loops to find all city pairs.

Answer (score 0):

It is classical, shortest path problem([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)).

Cities is vertices, highways between them - edges, number of degrees - lenght of shortest path from city to Washington DC.

Comment: Not quite.  All cities on a highway to DC have degree 1

Comment: @Gene, maybe I was not clear in description what is considered to be an edge: all cities on a highway has edges between them. So there is no problem - shortest path will be equal 1.